# jQuery "null" when assign a value

Tags: jquery, var

When I run this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $altura = $('.slb_container').height();
    console.log($altura);        
});
```

I get "null" on the console. But when I run `$('.slb_container').height();` directly in the console I get an integer value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add HTML context

Comment: Javascript / jQuery is not PHP and `$` is not enough to declare a variable. You can fix this by by declaring your variable like so: `var altura = $('.slb_container').height();`

Comment: @nbokmans it's normal, variables names can also begin with `$` and `_`, without keyword `var` it's like global variable...

Comment: Hi! @DoTheDew I'm trying to center vertically the ligthbox on mobile. Take a look! http://sociallab.pe/wordpress/galerias/derechos-humanos/prueba-de-galeria-5-columnas/ I think on get the ".slb_container" container heigth in order to set a "top" property. Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: @FrancoBermudez Please put that code here in your question. It's not good practice to redirect to external links

Comment: I'm Sorry, I really don't know @DoTheDew I'll try to upload a Jsfiddle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the property of an **array**. This is happening because you're getting all elements with the class of `.slb_container`.

You have 2 easy options:

1. Use a unique ID in your HTML to identify your element

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {    
      $altura = $('#slb_container_id').height();
      console.log($altura);        
   });
   ```
2. Index into your class array with `$('.slb_container')[i]` and then wrap it in `$()` to objectify it as a jQuery object.

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {    
      $altura = $($('.slb_container')[0]).height();
      console.log($altura);        
   });
   ```

Comment: Hi! @DoTheDew I still get the "null". It's strange because when I run into the Google Chrome Console directly I do get an integer "230" example.

Comment: @FrancoBermudez This is where posting some HTML or using a https://jsfiddle.net/ would be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only one element on your html with this class? I am not sure, but I think this is what happened. You are trying to get a height of something that is an array and not an element.
Try to put a unique ID instead

Comment: Hi! @Nicio-Barreto-Santos I do have one div with this class. That div has another div inside. But what is strange, is what I run "$('.slb_container').height();" directly in the  Google Chrome Console, I do get an integer "230" example.